# how to save date from visual basic.net to sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

hello guys am a beginner to vb.net am trying to make an application for my videos

i have a problem to insert birthdate of the actor to the sql server database

the birthdate field in sql server is set to date not datetime

let's say birthdate = 02-13-1980
when i click the save button am getting the error

incorrect syntax near '02-13-1980'

and thanks for your help

thi is my class

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SQL_Control

Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=TRUCK-PC\TRUCK;Database=Videos;User=sa;Pwd=123456;"}
Public SQLCmd As SqlCommand
Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
Public SQLDataset As DataSet


Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean

    Try

        SQLCon.Open()

        SQLCon.Close()
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Public Sub RunQuery(Query As String)

    Try

        SQLCon.Open()

        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
        SQLDataset = New DataSet
        SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

            SQLCon.Close()

        End If

    End Try

End Sub


Public Sub AddNewActor(S_ActorName As String, S_ActorNationality As String, S_ActorBirthDate As Date)

    Try
        Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO Videos (Actor_Name,Actor_Nationality,Actor_Birth_Date) " & _
                                         "VALUES (" & _
                                         "'" & S_ActorName & "'," & _
                                         "'" & S_ActorNationality & "'," & _
                                         "'" & S_ActorBirthDate & "'"

        MsgBox(strInsert)

        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)

        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

this is my form code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class F2_Actors

Dim SQL As New SQL_Control

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_actors WHERE tbl_actors.Actor_Name = '" & ActorName.Text & "' ")

    If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        MsgBox("Actor already exist", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Videos Database - Adding New Actor")

    Else

        AddActor()

    End If
End Sub

Public Sub AddActor()

    SQL.AddNewActor(ActorName.Text, ActorNationality.Text, ActorBirthDate.Text)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Post the code snippet you are having problems with.  Based on the error message, it looks like the `INSERT` has a syntax error and is also not parameterized.  Always use parameterized queries.

Comment: Dan guzman i put the code snippet could you hel me with the problem please. I found difficulty in adding parameters since i have the adding code in a class and then i call it in the specified form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the SQL syntax error is a missing close parenthesis at the end of the `VALUES` clause.

As I mentioned in my comment, once should always use parameterized queries for values that vary at run time.  This practice provide benefits of security, performance, and readability.  Below is a parameterized version using strongly-typed parameters.  Change the parameter data types and maximum characters lengths to match your actual table schema.

Note that I also schema-qualified the table name, another best practice that improves performance and avoids ambiguity.  I also added a semi-colon statement terminator since not using terminators is deprecated in SQL Server.

```
Public Sub AddNewActor(S_ActorName As String, S_ActorNationality As String, S_ActorBirthDate As Date)

    Try

        Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO dbo.Videos (Actor_Name,Actor_Nationality,Actor_Birth_Date) " & _
                             "VALUES (@Actor_Name, @Actor_Nationality, @Actor_Birth_Date);"

        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)
        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Actor_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = S_ActorName
        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Actor_Nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = S_ActorNationality
        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Actor_Birth_Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = S_ActorBirthDate

        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Also, avoid using `SELECT *` in queries and instead specify an explicit column list.  This practice can improve performance and provides a cleaner database interface.